R language : Error of cv.ncvreg :Error in object$beta[, which, drop = FALSE] : subscript out of bounds
When I used the cv.ncvreg function to fit the Poisson regression model, I met such problems:
cv.ncvreg(UTrans$X, UTrans$Y, family="poisson", penalty="SCAD", max.iter=20000)

Error in object$beta[, which, drop = FALSE] : subscript out of bounds

The data is fine since useing cv.glmnet have not given any error. I really have no idea and maybe the error is of cv.ncvreg itself?
Also, this cv.ncvreg is in a loop of i for (i in 1:25). I printed i whenever a round was done and found that when i > 8, the error discribed above ocurred. Could someone help me? Thanks!
I've tried what I mentioned above.

Hi! Welcome to SO! Be sure to provide a minimal reproducible example to best help with your error. You can do this by pasting the output of dput(UTrans) in your question, or find/create a dataset that reproduces the problem.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
